# Are $e^{-|t|}$ and $\cos{t}e^{-|t|}$ characteristic functions?

Tags: probability-theory

The task is to find out whether $e^{-|t|}$ and $\cos{t} e^{-|t|}$ are characteristic functions. I have previously proven that for $\cos^2t$ and $ \cos t$ by finding a discrete distribution whose characteristic function equal  $\cos^2t$ or $\cos t$ respectively. Here however, I got stuck with the modulus.

I tried tackling it with

$$
e^{-|t|} = e^{|it|}
$$
and random variable
$$
X(t) = 1 \text{ for } t \geq 0; X(t) = -1 \text{ for }t <0
$$
but it did not work.

Comment: Cauchy random variable, generally you can use Fourier transform results to find them as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Unfortunately, Fourier transforms or Cauchy's random variable were not yet introduced for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know $\cos t$ is a characteristic function, it suffices to prove $e^{-|t|}$ is one too. (Characteristic functions are closed under multiplication.) Indeed it is, namely for the standardized Cauchy distribution, which @KKMcDonald mentioned. In particular, its PDF is$$\frac{\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-|t|-itx}dt}{2\pi}=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{(1-ix)t}dt+\int_0^\infty e^{-(1+ix)t}dt}{2\pi}=\frac{\frac{1}{1-ix}+\frac{1}{1+ix}}{2\pi}=\frac{\pi^{-1}}{1+x^2},$$which you can easily verify integrates to $1$ on $\Bbb R$.